# EF6 e NPGSQL : Erro de violação da chave estrangeira

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, entity-framework-6

Boa tarde !
Sou novo em ASP.NET e EF6. Desenvolvia antes em PHP.

Criei um projeto (ASP.NET MVC) utilizando EF6 e NPGSQL. Apanhei um pouco ao criar os relacionamentos entre duas tabelas mas funcionou. A tabela persona terá vários países (1:n). Segue SQL, Model e context.

SQL:

```
 CREATE TABLE pais(
  idpais character(3) NOT NULL,
  nomepais character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_pais PRIMARY KEY (idpais),
  CONSTRAINT ix_nomepais UNIQUE (nomepais)
)

CREATE TABLE persona
(
  idpersona serial NOT NULL,
  nomepers character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  idpaispers character(3),
  CONSTRAINT pk_persona PRIMARY KEY (idpersona),
  CONSTRAINT fk_perspais FOREIGN KEY (idpaispers)
      REFERENCES pais (idpais) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT ix_nomepers UNIQUE (nomepers)
)
```

Model Pais

```
[Table("pais",Schema="public")]
public class Pais
{
    public Pais()
    {
        this.Persona = new HashSet<Persona>();
    }
    [Key]
    [Column("idpais")]
    [Display(Name = "Sigla")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(3)]
    [Required]
    public string IDPais { get; set; }

    [Column("nomepais")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Index("ix_nomepais",IsUnique=true)]
    [Required]
    public string nomePais { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Persona> Persona { get; set; }
}
```

Model Persona :

```
    [Table("persona", Schema="public")]
public class Persona
{
    [Key]
    [Column("idpersona")]
    public int IDPersona { get; set; }

    [Column("nomepers")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Index("ix_nomepers", IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    public string nomePers { get; set; }

    [Column("idpaispers")]
    [Display(Name = "País")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string idpaisPers { get; set; }
    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }

}
```

Context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Persona>()
                .HasRequired<Pais>(p => p.Pais)
                .WithMany(e => e.Persona)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.idpaisPers);
}
```

Na hora de incluir um "persona", propositalmente especifico um país que não está cadastrado, gerando um erro de violação de chave estrangeira do Postgres. Mas o EF não deveria fazer a validação antes ? Errei em algo ou devo incluir uma validação para que não ocorra este erro ?
Agradeço antecipadamente quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Na hora de incluir um "persona", propositalmente especifico um país que não está cadastrado, gerando um erro de violação de chave estrangeira do Postgres. Mas o EF não deveria fazer a validação antes?

Não, o Entity Framework não faz validação de chave estrangeira. A validação tem que ser feita no código do *Controller*.

> Errei em algo ou devo incluir uma validação para que não ocorra este erro?

Você pode capturar a exceção ou desenvolver um código preventivo no seu *Controller* para verificar se faz sentido a atribuição de Id do país em questão. Isso se faz por regras de negócio no *Controller*, que é a camada responsável por harmonizar as relações entre *Models*.

Comment: Agradeço pelo esclarecimento. Mas me surgiu uma dúvida de leigo: Se eu tenho que fazer a validação, qual a finalidade de "declarar" os relacionamentos ?

Comment: Aproveitar os recursos de carga preguiçosa e trabalhar os objetos a nível de aplicação. Por exemplo, uma atribuição de relação estrangeira, como por exemplo `persona.idPaisPers = 1`, é incorreta do ponto de vista do Entity Framework, mas prefeitamente válida se você fizer `persona.Pais = pais;`, sendo `pais` um objeto do tipo `Pais` previamente selecionado pelo Entity Framework.

Comment: Novamente, agradeço ao seu esclarecimento. Ficou mais fácil de entender.